# How to check my current version of Cardboard SDK for Unity, so that I can update it to the latest version (v0.5.1)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Latest version of Unity is here: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download

If I import the latest package, it throws a compiler error 
`Assets/Cardboard/Scripts/VRDevices/CardboardAndroidDevice.cs(18,14): error CS0101: The namespace global::' already contains a definition forCardboardAndroidDevice'`

Unity Version: Unity 5.1.1 Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/release-notes

Release notes for v0.5.1 explain:  You must remove the Assets/Cardboard/ folder, and all Cardboard-related libraries from the Assets/Plugins folder before upgrading.  (If you use no other plugins, just delete the Plugins folder itself.)

This is because a number of files got renamed and moved around for v0.5.1, but Unity's package importer doesn't look for that (it would be very difficult to do).  If you just import the new package, you get some files left over from the old version of the package, which leads to the error you see.